# System.DmlException error while trying to insert in custom field

Tags: custom-object

Hi i am trying to add items in salesforce custom fields though data loader , i am getting the below error when i am pushing the value in it

> ERROR: dlrs_School_GroupTrigger: execution of AfterInsertcaused by:
> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
> 0011U00001sOiteQAC; first error: FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,
> Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.:
> [Program_Primary_Contact_PO__c]Class.dlrs.RollupService.Updater.updateRecords: line 1381, column
> 1Class.dlrs.RollupService.UpdateWithoutSharing.updateRecords: line
> 1424, column 1Class.dlrs.RollupService.updateRecords: line 1352,
> column 1Class.dlrs.RollupService.handleRollups: line 1000, column
> 1Class.dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler: line 311, column
> 1Trigger.dlrs_School_GroupTrigger: line 7, column 1

i dont know while i am getting this error can anyone help me identify it

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! We don't know *how* you are getting that error. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/366170/edit) your question to add context (e.g., what you are running when that error appears). If you have code firing, share the pertinent code. It is difficult with so little to go on. Please help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

The debug log contains all information you need to know: There is an active lookup filter on the `Program_Primary_Contact_PO__c` field. This is why the `RollupService.Updater.updateRecords` fails to update the records. The updater is part of a trigger logic that is invoked because of the data you updated.

Now the interesting question is: Is the updated field part of the lookup filter (therefore, you created the error)? Or is the data corrupted (therefore, the error was already there)? Please provide us with more info of the "data" you want to push.